# Could one convert a node.js server local to your own computer into an online one?

Tags: javascript, node.js, localhost

I have a node.js server that I host locally on my own computer ("http://localhost:3000")

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, listen);
```

Would it be possible to change this localhost address to one of an online website? If I were to change it to "http://mywebsite.com", would it be accessible from there? Would it work?

Comment: If you are only interested in temporarily making your server publicly available and are not concerned with the specific url, [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) might be something worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

yes, first at all you need set the port to 80 instead 3000

second you need a public IP that you must contact with your ISP

third you need buy a domain maybe you should buy to your ISP too

fourth you need configure your domain to point to your public IP so when somebody write www.yoursite.com he will access to your pc

another alternative is

first at all you need set the port to 80 instead 3000

and second create a [no-ip](https://www.noip.com/login) account and configure your router

Answer (score 0):

you can try using something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/?WT.mc_id=13402-DEV-sitepoint-article26) to expose your localhost to the internet. so that others can access your localhost if they have the address.

You are unable to just change the localhost address to one of your own as it would only be know to you.